# Retrieving text file having the query text in MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a set of 100 text files. I give query 'a fat man is swimming in water', now the output should only be the name of text files that contain either 'fat','man' or 'swimming' or two of them or all three words (stopwords should not be considered while matching). And also how many words were matched in each text file.

Help in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
%%// Source of stopwords- http://norm.al/2009/04/14/list-of-english-stop-words/
stopwords_cellstring={'a', 'about', 'above', 'above', 'across', 'after', ...
    'afterwards', 'again', 'against', 'all', 'almost', 'alone', 'along', ...
    'already', 'also','although','always','am','among', 'amongst', 'amoungst', ...
    'amount',  'an', 'and', 'another', 'any','anyhow','anyone','anything','anyway', ...
    'anywhere', 'are', 'around', 'as',  'at', 'back','be','became', 'because','become',...
    'becomes', 'becoming', 'been', 'before', 'beforehand', 'behind', 'being', 'below',...
    'beside', 'besides', 'between', 'beyond', 'bill', 'both', 'bottom','but', 'by',...
    'call', 'can', 'cannot', 'cant', 'co', 'con', 'could', 'couldnt', 'cry', 'de',...
    'describe', 'detail', 'do', 'done', 'down', 'due', 'during', 'each', 'eg', 'eight',...
    'either', 'eleven','else', 'elsewhere', 'empty', 'enough', 'etc', 'even', 'ever', ...
    'every', 'everyone', 'everything', 'everywhere', 'except', 'few', 'fifteen', 'fify',...
    'fill', 'find', 'fire', 'first', 'five', 'for', 'former', 'formerly', 'forty', 'found',...
    'four', 'from', 'front', 'full', 'further', 'get', 'give', 'go', 'had', 'has', 'hasnt',...
    'have', 'he', 'hence', 'her', 'here', 'hereafter', 'hereby', 'herein', 'hereupon', ...
    'hers', 'herself', 'him', 'himself', 'his', 'how', 'however', 'hundred', 'ie', 'if',...
    'in', 'inc', 'indeed', 'interest', 'into', 'is', 'it', 'its', 'itself', 'keep', 'last',...
    'latter', 'latterly', 'least', 'less', 'ltd', 'made', 'many', 'may', 'me', 'meanwhile',...
    'might', 'mill', 'mine', 'more', 'moreover', 'most', 'mostly', 'move', 'much', 'must',...
    'my', 'myself', 'name', 'namely', 'neither', 'never', 'nevertheless', 'next', 'nine',...
    'no', 'nobody', 'none', 'noone', 'nor', 'not', 'nothing', 'now', 'nowhere', 'of', 'off',...
    'often', 'on', 'once', 'one', 'only', 'onto', 'or', 'other', 'others', 'otherwise',...
    'our', 'ours', 'ourselves', 'out', 'over', 'own','part', 'per', 'perhaps', 'please',...
    'put', 'rather', 're', 'same', 'see', 'seem', 'seemed', 'seeming', 'seems', 'serious',...
    'several', 'she', 'should', 'show', 'side', 'since', 'sincere', 'six', 'sixty', 'so',...
    'some', 'somehow', 'someone', 'something', 'sometime', 'sometimes', 'somewhere', ...
    'still', 'such', 'system', 'take', 'ten', 'than', 'that', 'the', 'their', 'them',...
    'themselves', 'then', 'thence', 'there', 'thereafter', 'thereby', 'therefore', ...
    'therein', 'thereupon', 'these', 'they', 'thickv', 'thin', 'third', 'this', 'those',...
    'though', 'three', 'through', 'throughout', 'thru', 'thus', 'to', 'together', 'too',...
    'top', 'toward', 'towards', 'twelve', 'twenty', 'two', 'un', 'under', 'until', 'up',...
    'upon', 'us', 'very', 'via', 'was', 'we', 'well', 'were', 'what', 'whatever', 'when',...
    'whence', 'whenever', 'where', 'whereafter', 'whereas', 'whereby', 'wherein',...
    'whereupon', 'wherever', 'whether', 'which', 'while', 'whither', 'who', 'whoever',...
    'whole', 'whom', 'whose', 'why', 'will', 'with', 'within', 'without', 'would', 'yet',...
    'you', 'your', 'yours', 'yourself', 'yourselves', 'the'};

%%// Keywords
key1 = 'man';
key2 = 'swimming';

%%// Read in all TXT files
txtfiles = dir('*.txt');

%%// Go through all files
for k0 = 1:numel(txtfiles)

    %%// Read in strings from one text file at a time
    fid = fopen(txtfiles(k0).name);
    textdata = textscan(fid, '%s','delimiter', '\n');
    fclose(fid);

    %%// Get the count of strings to be matched
    count1 = 0;
    for k = 1:numel(textdata{1})

        %%// Read line and split into words
        split1 = regexp(cell2mat(textdata{1}(k)),'\s','Split');

        %%// If number of words are less than two, move onto the next line
        if numel(split1)<2
            continue;
        end

        %%// Remove the stopwords
        split1 = split1(~ismember(split1,stopwords_cellstring')); %%//'

        %%// Get the count of consecutive appearance of keywords
        chkpatt1 = ismember(split1,key1);
        chkpatt2 = ismember(split1,key2);
        count1 = count1 + nnz(sum([0 chkpatt1;chkpatt2 0],1)==2);

    end

    %%// Store filenames and counts as a cell array
    outcell(k0,1) = {txtfiles(k0).name};
    outcell(k0,2) = num2cell(count1);

end
```

For testing it out, use this code and instructions mentioned in it -

```
%%// Testing : Keep only one TXT file, let us name it as 'check1.txt' inside the 
%%// working directory and make sure that this has the keywords somewhere.
txtfiles = dir('*.txt');
if numel(txtfiles)~=1
    error('You do not have exactly one TXT file');
end
filename = cell2mat(outcell(1,1))
counts = cell2mat(outcell(1,2))
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, but the outcell is always showing 0 for its count value and also the chkpatt1 and 2 also showing zero, means no matching word found, but i have replaced the key1 and key2 with the same words as in the textfiles.

Comment: @user3416063 Do the testing as mentioned in the last part of the answer.

Comment: i used the testing code, but still count returns 0.

Comment: Can you just put one line in the text file and edit it as "The man is swimming" and see what is `counts`?

Comment: You understand that this code would look for a pattern like `man somestopword swimming`, right? `man` and `swimming` can't be separated by anything other than stopword(s).

Comment: Just click on the `outcell` variable from the workspace, it would show up on the `Variable Editor`, where you can see the filenames and corresponding counts.

Comment: i want the count stop word should return 1 even if 'man' and 'swimming' are not coming together. Example: count = 1 for statements like 'man is swimming' ,'swimming man' .

Comment: You are saying , if it encounters a string like `man is swimming`, then it must increase the count, but if it encounters something like `swimming man`, the counter must not be increased? Please make your requirements clear.

Comment: Sir, i want that it must return a numerical value like count = 1 for both files that have 'man is swimming' and also 'swimming man'. I will give query as statement like 'man is swimming in lake', and then find which text files contain the matching keywords ignoring stopwords. After finding the matched keywords it must return in which file how many keywords are matched. Example--i give query 'a fat man is swimming in water', now the output should be text files that contain either 'fat','man' or 'swimming' or two of them or all three words. And also how many words were matched in each text file.